# Formulário de cadastro - Liberar área de conteúdo

Tags: wordpress

Tenho uma área na `home` do meu site onde quero que, ao clicar para ver a matéria ou fazer download, abra um formulário de cadastro e depois de preencher, seja liberado a navegação normal do site.

Meu problema é fazer com que, quando ele navegar no site e voltar para `home` o formulário não apareça novamente.

Comment: Tipo um Pop-up?

Comment: Caso você ache mais fácil, você pode criar uma outra página com o fórmulario e dessa página liberar o download e redirecionar para a home de volta.

Comment: Utilize sessions do php e um if verificando se a session foi criada.

Comment: Sim, um pop-up.

Comment: a área de download é uma div